# Is helm able to fulfil such a requirement

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, helmfile

I have a requirement that my server is divided into normal game service and battle service, currently the release name can only be named xxxx. but now I want to update the battle service first, and then update the game service, and the release name must be the same. helm can satisfy this requirement? (Or can helmfile do it?).

I haven't found the right solution yet.

Comment: Can you say a little more about what you need, and what you've tried?  If service A needs to be fully updated and running before B can be updated, I think Helmfile `needs:` can do this, but plain Helm can't.  (If you can tolerate new-A, old-B in the middle of this upgrade sequence, can you tolerate arbitrary combinations of deployed versions?)

Comment: Of the top of my head, I would create a meta helm chart which has helm charts for `battleservice` and `gameservice` as [dependencies](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_dependency/). That being said: It is extremely bad from an architectural PoV to have the services depend on startup order. What do you do when the cluster rebalances? Or when a node goes down?

Comment: The process I'm trying is this: assuming there are multiple lines of server configurations running right now, with the game and combat suits, I'd comment out the game suits in the VALUES file first, then upgrade them using UPGRADE, so that I could update the combat suits first, and then the game suits more finely, but it doesn't feel very scientific to do it this way! (A and B can exist at the same time, but it's better if they don't.)@DavidMaze

Comment: Creating a dependency I feel doesn't satisfy my needs because I want to have the same release name@MarkusWMahlberg